# Where are the instructions for MAAS when one does not own the network?

Tags: maas

Where are the instructions for MAAS when one does not own the network?  Did I miss it? I see the instructions for using MAAS if I own the network and can setup my own DHCP server, but I failed to find the instructions for using MAAS when I do not own the network.  I would like to create a test cloud at work, but the network guys aren't going to allow me to run a DHCP server on their network, how do I do this?  The docs I saw at this URL:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS

claimed to cover the case:

- You're experimenting while using someone else's network: you can't allow MAAS to own the network's DHCP.

but I did not see any instructions for that case.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the answer is in the section: From the Ubuntu Server Installer from USB Stick, but the first option is: TODO - Insert example, so it's not clear.  I'm not actually trying it right now, I'm trying to read about it first since my time to actually do it will be limited.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Instructions are the same but you have to manually edit your DHCP server configuration to include DHCP options 66 (PXE server) and 67 (filename which will be "/pxelinux.0")

Comment: Didn't he say specifically that he can't set up/change the DHCP server config?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  nickguletskii is correct, I cannot control the existing DHCP server on the network and adding another DHCP server that I could control on the same network would cause problems would it not?  Also we already have a PXE server (Fog server) on the network as well that we use to image workstations.